# Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

Exception thrown when handling an exception

> (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException:
>   [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Roote" in method
>   App\Controller\BlogController::show() was never imported. [Did you
>   maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkVam.png) in
>   C:\Users\younes\Desktop\demo\config/routes../../src/Controller/
>   (which is being imported from
>   "C:\Users\younes\Desktop\demo\config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make
>   sure annotations are installed and enabled.)

[the image link down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkVam.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your annotation:

```
@Roote
```

To:

```
@Route
```